# How to log into the mobile app with my Facebook account?

Tags: support, login

I scrolled down the page and noticed that you have an available app for mobile users. I decided to download it so that I'd be able to check my answers and also to answer some questions through my mobile. However, as soon as I downloaded the app, I tried to log in my account, only to realize that *there is no* function of logging in by Facebook, so how am I supposed to log in my account since there is no such feature? Is there any other way? My account is only accessed through Facebook — is there any way to create a password to the account so that I can log into my account through that pass?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can follow the first procedure in [the Help Center](//ell.stackexchange.com/help/edit-credentials) when on the website to add an OpenID login. In particular, consider [using Stack Exchange's own OpenID provider](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers/114704#114704).

Comment: I added a new login method through Google, so I downloaded the app into my mobile, When I want to log into my account through the mobile, should I use the Google account which I associated my account with?

Comment: Yeah, that should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion on the overall StackExchange Meta that explains that you have to have the official Facebook app installed:

[Login with Facebook using Stack Exchange Android App](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230998/login-with-facebook-using-stack-exchange-android-app)

I don't use Facebook, so I can't test to see if anything has changed since 2014 when the question was was asked but I think it should work.